# A templated 'strdup()'?

Tags: c++, templates, memcpy, strdup

```
template<typename T>
static T *anydup(const T *src, size_t len) {
    T *ptr = malloc(len * sizeof(T));
    memcpy(ptr, src, (len * sizeof(T)));
    return ptr;
}
```

Is this proper? Can I expect any errors from this when using an int, long, etc.? I'm very new to generic programming and am trying to learn more.

Comment: `memcpy` is not a valid way to create objects in general. So no, don't do this. Try `std::vector<T>` instead.

Comment: Neither is `malloc` a valid way to instantiate objects.

Comment: The proper way to duplicate some `src` is `auto src2{src};`.

Comment: You might add a `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "T must be trivially copyable");`

Comment: How would you use `std::vector<T>` to that effect? Could someone provide an example, please? :)

Comment: With vector it will look like `std::vector<int> vec = otherVec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not proper !  When you have a `malloc()` in C++ code, you should become very suspicious:

- `malloc()` allocates memory, but doesn't properly create objects.  The only way to work with such memory would be to use a placement new.
- `memcpy()` doesn't respect the copy semantic of C++ objects.  This could only work with trivially copiable classes.  I would cause hard to find bugs elsewhere (shallow copies, and other awful things that lead to UB).

For basic types like char, int, double, it would work.  But not for more complex types.

---

Alternative 1: adapt your code to properly create and copy objects

```
template<typename T>
T *anydup (const T *src, size_t len) {
    T *ptr = new T[len];                        // requires that T has a default constructor
    copy (src, src+len, ptr);                   // requires that T is copyiable
    return ptr;
}
```

Attention: risk of memory leakage if user forget to delete the array, or UB if user doesnet use `delete[]` !  To avoid this you could opt for returning `unique_ptr<T[]>`.

---

Alternative 2: Get rid of arrays and pointers and memory nightmares: use vectors !

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> anydup (const vector<T> src) {
    vector<T> v(len);                        // requires that T has a default constructor
    copy (src.cbegin(), src.cend(), v);      // requires that T is copyable
    return v;
}
```

You could consider creating the vector using a copy constructor as suggested by Remy Lebeau and FDinoff in the comments, either in the function or directly in the using code.

If you use `copy()` directly in the using code, you'll soon discover that there are also `copy_if()`, `copy_backwards()` and some other nice `<algorithms>` that could be used depending on circumstances.

Comment: @PhobosD'thorga you're welcome !  please see my edit for alternative solutions.  I didn't test it so there might be typos in it.

Comment: Wow, thank you! And the examples are fantastic. I really have learned a heap with regard to merging the two worlds of C and C++ :) If I may ask one more thing, what does 'UB' stand for?

Comment: In Alternative 2. Please just use the copy constructor and don't create an anydup method.

Comment: @PhobosD'thorga UB means Undefined Behaviour (e.g. the kind of things that could happen if you dereference a NULL pointer -- sorry, a `nullptr`).  - and yes C and C++ are close, but there are some key differences.  In short, you need to understand the object model and the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  Many pointer solutions simply are no longer required if you replace `char*`with the more powerful `string`, and arrays with vectors.

Comment: In alternative 2, you might consider using the vector constructor that accepts iterators as input: `template<typename T>
vector<T> anydup (const vector<T> &src) {
return vector<T>(src.cbegin(), src.cend()); }`

Comment: Or even the copy constructor: `template<typename T>
vector<T> anydup (const vector<T> &src) {
return vector<T>(src); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau even better !!  This shows that if we have a hammer in the hand, every problem look like a nail ;-)

Comment: Your point about `malloc()` only being usable in combination with placement-new is not correct: `malloc()`-allocations can be used for objects that don't need construction. Like an array of `char`, for instance, or other plain-old-data objects. After all, all uses of `malloc()` are correct within a C program that is also valid C++, and none of those use placement-new by definition.

Comment: @cmaster thanks for giving me the opportunity to clarify: just look at my statement below the second bullet (*"For basic types like char, int, double, it would work"*). Nevertheless, the purpose of OP is to have a generic copy function, and malloc will not work for other types like for example `std::string`.  Do you think there's any advantage in C++ to use  `malloc()` for some types and  `new` for other instead of using new in all the cases ?

Comment: Well, my point was not about advantages or disadvantages, it was about what is possible. And, yes, a C++ program may need to use `malloc()` when it has to interact with pure C libraries. For instance, you cannot use `asprintf()` from C++ without also inserting at least one call to `free()` into your program.

Comment: I am interacting with pure C libraries, within a C++ program, actually. Good observation, @cmaster.

Comment: @cmaster ok ! C interoperability is a valid point. And that would imply the use of POD data which should not suffer from the lack of object model support.